# Set clim to colormap in plt.subblots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I want to color the points on a scatterplot by a variable `percent_mito`.
I added the arguments `c = my_data.obs['percent_mito'], cmap = 'viridis` to `scatter()`, but I want the `clim` to be (0,0.1), since that is where the bulk of my data lies and what I'm interested in seeing here.

I tried `axs[0].set_clim(0,0.1)` , but that doesn't work.

How can I specify the limits for a cmap?

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,4.5))

axs[0].scatter(my_data.obs['n_counts'], my_data.obs['n_genes'],
 c=my_data.obs['percent_mito'], cmap='viridis',s=2)

axs[0].set_xlabel('n_counts')
axs[0].set_ylabel('n_genes')

axs[0].axhline(500, color='red')
axs[0].axvline(1000, color='red')
axs[0].axvline(35000, color='red')


axs[1].scatter(my_data.obs['n_genes'], my_data.obs['percent_mito'], s=2)
axs[1].set_xlabel('n_genes')
axs[1].set_ylabel('percent_mito')
axs[1].axhline(10, color='red')
axs[1].axvline(500, color='red')


plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, considering the right subplot, will data points with `percent_mito` > 0.1 have the same colour as `percent_mito` = 0.1 such that the colour gradient will exit for values between 0 and 0.1?

Comment: Yes. I only want the colormap to occupy the range from 0-10, and everything >10 should be the highest color (=10)

Comment: `axs[0].scatter(...., vmin=0, vmax=10)`?  Or `axs[0].scatter(...., vmin=0, vmax=0.1)`?  See also [colormap normalization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html)